# TypeError: Cannot read property '_isDestroyed' of undefined Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using nuxt.js i get this error "6b486774c601587bc79c.js:2 TypeError: Cannot read property '_isDestroyed' of undefined"  in only one page, it disapear when i visit other pages than i back to this page

Comment: Comment out code until it goes away, or try git bisect to find the offending commit. You need to find the piece of code that's causing the issue. You'll probably solve the problem yourself at that point, but if not come back and update the question. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I got this error while writing a test. Updated `@vue/test-utils` from `1.0.0-beta.29` to `1.1.0` and the problem went away.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, at the end of the day it was a svg tag inside my Vue component that crashed the app. Don't know why, if somebody knows please share.
I just replaced it putting the svg within an img tag. Not proud but it works.

Comment: What I noticed was if you have a style that references outside the vue-app scope. E.g. targeting the html dom element in styles. Then it'll cause this as well. Example, html has overflow hidden, and the app control scope starts at the body.. It was not limited to, but this was one of the causes as well. hope it helps.