# Nuxt2 app using Vuetity returns "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_isDestroyed')" in Cloudflare

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, cloudflare

I'm having a problem with an Nuxt2 + Vuetify application only when hosting in cloudflare. The application works fine when running locally. So it seems to be related to the cloudflare hosting environment.

```
50207d9.js:2 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_isDestroyed')
    at destroy (50207d9.js:2:157430)
    at b (50207d9.js:2:195189)
    at b (50207d9.js:2:195288)
    at b (50207d9.js:2:195288)
    at a.__patch__ (50207d9.js:2:198658)
    at t.$destroy (50207d9.js:2:171214)
    at destroy (50207d9.js:2:157630)
    at b (50207d9.js:2:195189)
    at a.__patch__ (50207d9.js:2:198658)
    at t.$destroy (50207d9.js:2:171214)
```

Here is the package-lock.js for versions:

```
"node_modules/@nuxtjs/vuetify": {
        "version": "1.12.3",
        "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@nuxtjs/vuetify/-/vuetify-1.12.3.tgz",
        "integrity": "sha512-...",
        "dev": true,
        "dependencies": {
            "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
            "sass": "~1.32.13",
            "sass-loader": "^10.2.0",
            "vuetify": "^2.6",
            "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.3"
        }
    },
```

I have been commenting out sections of the page to work out what exactly is causing this error at render time, and it seems to be related to a couple of different things.

Here is the first example from Vuetify tabs:

```
       <v-tabs v-model="calculatorTab" dark centered>
          <v-tabs-slider></v-tabs-slider>
          <v-tab href="#tab-1">
            <v-icon>bookmark</v-icon>
          </v-tab>
          <v-tab href="#tab-2">
            <v-icon>dialpad</v-icon>
          </v-tab>
        </v-tabs>
        <v-tabs-items dark v-model="calculatorTab" color="transparent">
          <v-tab-item value="tab-1" class="presets-container">
             ...
          </v-tab-item>
          <v-tab-item value="tab-2">
             ...
          </v-tab-item>
        </v-tabs-items>
```

This is just a standard vuetify tabs component. If I comment this out, the error disappears...

The second options is a basic custom component that uses HTML elements with a couple of named slots.

```
<template>
    <screen-16-by-9>
        <slot></slot>
          <div class="anchor-top-left" @click='emitClick($event, "anchor-top-left")'>
            <slot name="top-left"></slot>
          </div>
          <div class="anchor-top-center" @click='emitClick($event, "anchor-top-center")'>
            <slot name="top-center"></slot>
          </div>
          <div class="anchor-top-right" @click='emitClick($event, "anchor-top-right")'>
            <slot name="top-right"></slot>
          </div>
          <div class="anchor-center-left" @click='emitClick($event, "anchor-center-left")'>
            <slot name="left"></slot>
          </div>
          <div class="anchor-center-center" @click='emitClick($event, "anchor-center-center")'>
            <slot name="center"></slot>
          </div>
          <div class="anchor-center-right" @click='emitClick($event, "anchor-center-right")'>
            <slot name="right"></slot>
          </div>
          <div class="anchor-bottom-left" @click='emitClick($event, "anchor-bottom-left")'>
            <slot name="bottom-left"></slot>
          </div>
          <div class="anchor-bottom-center" @click='emitClick($event, "anchor-bottom-center")'>
            <slot name="bottom-center"></slot>
          </div>
          <div class="anchor-bottom-right" @click='emitClick($event, "anchor-bottom-right")'>
            <slot name="bottom-right"></slot>
          </div>
    </screen-16-by-9>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      emitClick(e, slice) {
          this.$emit('sliceClick', {
              slice,
              event:e
          })
      }
   }
}
```

This is obviously a 9-slice of the display, and it's using the standard vue slots. Nothing else is really going on here, except for the event emit.

Again ALL these work fine locally, it only seems to show it's face when loading on the cloudflare pages hosting.

Cloudflare it using the command 'nuxt generate' to build the site. So it's just a static vue site hosted on the CDN. I'm not using SSR or anything like that really.

So my question is has anyone nailed down what causes this error? I don't want to have to walk through the entire site reworking components that are working fine elsewhere, when then might be a simple answer.

I have viewed this [TypeError: Cannot read property '_isDestroyed' of undefined Vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61733478/typeerror-cannot-read-property-isdestroyed-of-undefined-vuejs)
And it works, it just seems like too much rework, and I feel there must be a more straight for answer...